# How can I link a js file from a resource folder in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new in laravel and vue. I'm trying to link the app.js in my welcome.blade.php but it shows the public folder instead of the resource folder in the console window.

welcome.blade,php

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="app">
        <articles></articles>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js\app.js') }}">

  </script>
</body>
```

console window displays

```
<script src="http://localhost/vuecrud2/public/assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

folder structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymozw.png)

Comment: The resource app.js compiles to the public app.js file. Run npm run dev and see the code now in your public app.js

Comment: See here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix

Comment: Thank you @AlexHarris it's working now, I got confused in the app.js inside public and resource folders.